# facebook login for websites works in desktop but not in ios safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have a working Facebook login for a website.it works in android device and desktop but not in safari .it gives me an error "domain of the url is not registered".So i change my url in app from http://example.com to http://www.example.com (). Now it works in iphone but i got an error in android devices "domain of the url is not registered".
if i change back to http://example.com then again i phone login will not work .
in facebook app i cant able to add multiple domain.In gmail we can add more than one domain and there i can solve this problem .
Is there any way to solve this issue so that same settings work for two devices

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: while creating a facebook app we have to give Site URL. if i give "http://" example.com then i can login from android mobile using crome or other browsers.
if i give "http://www"then example.com  it works in iphone but not in android devices [i think i cant share my url here ]